# Put multiple CSliderCtrl in CMFCToolbar as toolbar buttons

Tags: c++, mfc, slider, toolbar, cmfctoolbar

[image]

I need multiple slider in MFCToolbar as its buttons. I can put slider in toolbar and shows slider. But I can't send slider position change message to parent toolbar or parent mainframe class. Also can not show tooltip for current position of slider.

These are steps to do it:

1. I derived a class `clsMySlider` from `CSliderCtrl`, overloaded its `OnHScroll` method
2. Derived a class from `CMFCToolbarButton` `clsMySliderButton` and put an instance of `clsMySlider` inside it.
3. Added a method `Initialize` to `clsMySliderButton` and create instance of `clsMySlider` in this method
4. `m_pParent` and `m_pToolbar` are `CWnd*` of mainframe window and MFC toolbar pointers
5. Used `CMFCToolbar::ReplaceButton` to replace my first and second button of toolbar with 2 instances of `clsMySliderButton`
6. Overloaded `OnHScroll` method in MainFarme window to catch messages which Windows send to main frame

```
void clsMySlider::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    ::PostMessage(m_pParent->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_SLIDER_HSCROLL, NULL, nPos);
    ::PostMessage(m_pToolbar->GetSafeHwnd(), WM_SLIDER_HSCROLL, NULL, nPos);

    CSliderCtrl::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
void CMainFrame::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
        int dummyVar=nPos;

    CFrameWndEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

but problem is `OnHScroll` never gets called in `clsMySlider` or `CMainFrame` window.

I appreciate your help.please let me know how to send position change events to parent toolbar and parent mainframe window and how can I show tooltip to show slider position.

```
class clsMySlider : public CSliderCtrl
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(clsMySlider)

public:
    clsMySlider(CWnd* parent, CMFCToolBar* toolbar);
    virtual ~clsMySlider();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    CWnd* m_pParent;
    CMFCToolBar* m_pToolbar;
public:
    afx_msg void OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
    afx_msg void OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar);
};
```

```
class clsMySliderButton : public CMFCToolBarButton
{
public:
    clsMySliderButton ();
    virtual ~clsMySliderButton ();

public:
    CWnd* GetParentWnd();
    
    virtual BOOL CanBeDropped(CMFCToolBar* pToolbar) { return FALSE; }//So user can not position this button on a toolbar or menu during customization.
    virtual BOOL CanBeStored() const { return FALSE; }//So button cannot be stored as part of a drag-and-drop operation
    virtual BOOL CanBeStretched() const { return TRUE; }//So button can be stretched in customization mode
    virtual HWND GetHwnd();
    virtual const CRect GetInvalidateRect() const;
    virtual BOOL HaveHotBorder() const { return TRUE; }//So a border of the button is not displayed when a user selects the button
    virtual BOOL OnBeforeDrag() const { return FALSE; }//So disable dragging of the button
    virtual SIZE OnCalculateSize(CDC* pDC, const CSize& sizeDefault, BOOL bHorz);
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC,const CRect& rect,CMFCToolBarImages* pImages,BOOL bHorz = TRUE,BOOL bCustomizeMode = FALSE,BOOL bHighlight = FALSE,BOOL bDrawBorder = TRUE,BOOL bGrayDisabledButtons = TRUE);
    //virtual BOOL OnGetCustomToolTipText(CString& strToolTip);
    virtual void OnSize(int iSize);
    virtual BOOL SetACCData(CWnd* pParent, CAccessibilityData& data) { return FALSE; }//So toolbar button does not provide accessibility data
    virtual void SetStyle(UINT nStyle);
    BOOL Initialize(CRect r, CWnd* pParent, CMFCToolBar* pToolbar);
    virtual HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
    {
        CBrush b;
        b.CreateSolidBrush(NULL_BRUSH);
        return (HBRUSH)b.GetSafeHandle();
    }
    virtual BOOL OnUpdateToolTip(CWnd* pWndParent, int iButtonIndex, CToolTipCtrl& wndToolTip, CString& str)
    {
        if (!m_pSlider || iButtonIndex!=10)
            return FALSE;
        str.Format(L"Current Value=%d", m_pSlider->GetPos());
        return TRUE;
    }
    virtual BOOL OnToolHitTest(const CWnd* pWnd,TOOLINFO* pTI);
    virtual BOOL IsOwnerOf(HWND hwnd) 
    {
        if (!m_pSlider)
            return FALSE;
        return hwnd == m_pSlider->GetSafeHwnd(); 
    }
    virtual void OnChangeParentWnd(CWnd* pWndParent)
    {

    }
private :
    clsMySlider* m_pSlider;
    CMFCToolTipCtrl* m_pTooltip;
    CWnd* m_pParent;

};
```

```
 //Inside CMainFrame::OnCreate
//CMFCToolBar       m_wndToolBar;
//clsMySliderButton m_ZoomSlider;
       CRect r;
    m_wndToolBar.GetItemRect(10, &r);
    r.right += r.Width() * 3;
    m_ZoomSlider.Initialize(r, this, &m_wndToolBar);
    m_wndToolBar.ReplaceButton(10, m_ZoomSlider);
    m_wndToolBar.UpdateButton(10);
```

Comment: What is the `WM_SLIDER_HSCROLL` message? If you meant `WM_HSCROLL`, then it looks like your `wParam` and `lParam` are wrong (mixed-up)?

Comment: But, maybe not really helpful, but you should probably consider using a `CDialogBar` class instead of `CMFCToolBar`, as that allows for more types of embedded controls.

Comment: That's a user-defined message that I want to send to parent window.but program control never reach there.First I thought when slider changes position,CSliderCtrl::OnHScroll is called,but it not happened,Then I though maybe Windows send HScroll message to parent windows so I overloaded CMainFrame::OnHScroll,still no success.The only thing I didn't check is maybe Windows send HScroll message to CMFCToolbar object.I  will check it and then write the result

Comment: That's why I think a toolbar derived from `CDialogBar` would be better - it allows you to add `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()` in your derived class and then implement a `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP()` which has the handlers for the various slider control messages.

Comment: Right,your suggestion works.this solution also works.I derived a class from CMFCToolbar and overloadded its WM_HSCROLL message handler as you suggested.each slider control in this toolbar sends its message to this toolbar and I could catch it inside this handler.thank you for nice suggestion which game me a clue for solution.